# Primefaces components not rendering in browser

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsf-2, primefaces

Am just starting of with primefaces 5.2.The problem is i can't just figure out why primefaces components doesn't show up in the browser though other jsp components do show.
My web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.joseph</groupId>
<artifactId>com.joseph.test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

my sample page index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<p:editor />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Browser page source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head id="j_idt2"></head><body>
<p:editor></p:editor></body>
</html>
```

IDE intellij idea 2016.2.1 glassfish server 4.1.1 ubuntu 15.10;Thanks

Comment: I checked this one: http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted
Try to add `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" ` respectively `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` to your html tag

Comment: i still get the same results.no success.

Comment: Finally figured out.I was not packaging the dependencies in my artifact.

Comment: I suggest you post your solution as answer for other users in future :)